# How do I align my navbar to the right of my html page?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to align the simple navigation bar I've created to the right of my HTML page but in a fixed position (per the requirement of FreeCodeCamp) so that when I scroll up or down I can always see it. I've tried various things such as float: right, different flexbox properties, text-align: right, margin properties... yet nothing worked and I'm just getting frustrated because its something so simple. Can anyone please look at my code and advise me what I should do? I'm new to this so please excuse my poorly written code.

```css
.nav-link {
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  display: inline;
   
}

#nav-bar {
position: fixed;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-link">
  <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us</a> | 
  <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services</a> |
  <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
</div>
          </nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVxn.png)

The result of what I have so far is what is shown in the image I included...

Thanks so much.

Comment: so what is your issue? you can see it always when you scroll up or down because its position is fixed

Comment: I am trying to align my navigation bar to the right of the HTML page

Comment: just add `right:0` style with `position: fixed`

Comment: That helps! That was able to move it to the right all the way... But now how can i move it up though so theres no awkward space even when I am all the way at the top of the page?

Comment: add `top:0`, i just answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `top` and `right` style for the fixed position.

```css
.nav-link {
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  display: inline;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-link">
    <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us</a> |
    <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services</a> |
    <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use float: right; for make it align right

```
    .nav-link {
      font-size: 23px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: end;
      display: inline;
       
    }

    #nav-bar {
    float: right;
     
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
      <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-link">
      <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us</a> | 
      <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services</a> |
      <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
    </div>
              </nav>
```

Comment: Hmm... when I do that it moves the image of my truck to the left a little..